# Canvas-engine and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fancybox, canvasengine

So the problem is easy. I want canvas-engine in the fancybox. So when I click on some fancybox item it loads some file in it. I that file I have added canvas-engine and script file where I write my scenes and the game. But I cant get it working it does not initialize the `<canvas>` tag.

This how I do that:

```
var canvas = CE.defines("game").extend(Hit).extend(Animation).ready(function() { 
    canvas.Scene.call("MyScene");
});
```

It does not appear when I open fancybox, and there is no error in the console either.